# How do I uninstall StarCraft II on OS X?

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

I can't seem to find an obvious way of uninstalling StarCraft II on OS X. What's the standard procedure for this?

For what it's worth, I've found two directories that are obviously related to StarCraft II so far.

- `/Applications/StarCraft II`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/StarCraft II`

A few other points to consider:

- Is it easy enough to reinstall the game later?
- Do I have to worry about deleting save games or is that all stored on the server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard procedure is just moving the *Starcraft II* folder from *Applications* to the *Trash*. Your save-games,replays etc. are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/Starcraft II/`. If you keep that folder, your save-games should still be there after a re-install. I haven't tested this though, so I suggest you make a backup copy of that folder before you perform a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes the obvious solution really is the answer!

Comment: You can find more details instructions here https://sea.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-uninstall-instructions

Answer (score 1):

If you have StarCraft II, you probably installed it from Battle.net in the first place. If you look at the game's tab, there is a settings gear icon with a drop-down menu which has an uninstall option. Battle.net tracks your progress and saves in the games that are linked to it, so reinstalling later will recover this data. No sweat!